# What does `_?` mean in Swift?

Tags: swift

Few days ago, I converted my old Xcode 8 project to Swift 4 in Xcode 9.
I noticed additional Swift codes generated along with explanation just above the code.

Here what it looks like:

```
// FIXME: comparison operators with optionals were removed from the Swift Standard Libary.
// Consider refactoring the code to use the non-optional operators.
fileprivate func < <T : Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
  switch (lhs, rhs) {
  case let (l?, r?):
    return l < r
  case (nil, _?):
    return true
  default:
    return false
  }
}
```

I tried to understand what the code does and find what I think is kind of unusual `_?` in the code.

I guess it is unused optional because `_` means we are not going to use a particular variable so we don't care about a variable's name and `?` is optional syntax.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: it means _"it is optional and not being interested in what that is"_.

Comment: Thinking about it again I am not sure if it is a 100% duplicate. Here `_?` is the *optional* pattern with a wildcard pattern. It matches anything that is not nil.

Comment: I did aware of  `_` meaning. But to see it paired with `?` is kinda unusual. Thats what I ask rather than meaning of plain `_`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_` is the *wildcard pattern* which matches anything, see for example

- [Swift : What does "_, _ " means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36513031/swift-what-does-means)
- [Why do I need underscores in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627106/why-do-i-need-underscores-in-swift)

And `x?` is the *optional* pattern, a shortcut for `.some(x)`, it matches
an optional which is not `nil`.

Here we have the combination of both: `_?` matches anything that is
not `nil`.

`case (nil, _?)` matches if the left operand is `nil`
and the right operand is not. You could also write it as `case (.none, .some)`.

Xcode can insert this function during migration from older Swift versions,
compare [Strange generic function appear in view controller after converting to swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251005/strange-generic-function-appear-in-view-controller-after-converting-to-swift-3).

Comment: I tried to remove `?` from `_?` so it becomes `case (nil, _)`  and turns out that the code works the same way as it was with `_?`.

So I think the use of `?` here is to emphasize that we deal with optional instead of ordinary variable. CMIW. Thank you.

Comment: @fitsyu: Without the question mark “nil < nil” would be true (which is wrong). You can try it with `let a: Int? = nil ; print(a < a)`

Comment: right. I hereby confirm that.
thanks @Martin R. well appreciated.